# Вызов модального окна в Java

Tags: окно, java, netbeans, swing

Есть окно с пунктом меню <kbd>Нарисовать</kbd>→<kbd>Ромб</kbd> (все создается в NetBeans).

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package my.graphics;
/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
public class GraphicsUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form GraphicsUI
     */
    public GraphicsUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem4 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenu1.setText("Нарисовать");

        jMenuItem1.setText("Ромб");
        jMenuItem1.setToolTipText("");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem3.setText("Треугольник");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuItem4.setText("Эллипс");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem4);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Выход");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jMenuItem1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        WindowForRhomb childwindowforrhomb=new WindowForRhomb();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jMenuItem1ActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GraphicsUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GraphicsUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GraphicsUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GraphicsUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new GraphicsUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem4;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

По нажатию этого пункта меню я хочу создать другой модальный `JFrame`, в котором задаются параметры рисования ромба (длина стороны и один из углов).Я создал это окно, добавив из контекстного меню к проекту форму `JFrame`

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package my.graphics;

/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
public class WindowForRhomb extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form WindowForRhomb
     */
    public WindowForRhomb() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Длина стороны");

        jLabel2.setText("Угол ромба");

        jButton1.setText("ОК");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 112, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(126, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(60, 60, 60))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 164, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(44, 44, 44))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WindowForRhomb.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WindowForRhomb.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WindowForRhomb.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WindowForRhomb.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new WindowForRhomb().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Как видно из кода

```
    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jMenuItem1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        WindowForRhomb childwindowforrhomb=new WindowForRhomb();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jMenuItem1ActionPerformed
```

По нажатию пункта меню - <kbd>рисовать</kbd>, должно быть создано модальное окно `childwindowforrhomb`. Но по нажатию кнопки ничего не происходит. Почему? Как исправить эту ситуацию, чтобы создавалось модальное окно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        WindowForRhomb childwindowforrhomb=new WindowForRhomb();
              childwindowforrhomb.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: @Gorets при попытке ввести метод show не отображается и после ввода подчеркивает красным метод show.

Comment: поправил  ...

Comment: @Gorets см. http://hashcode.ru/questions/165443/java-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-setvisible